# Meshing algorithms mess up Triangulation_vertex_base_with_id_2

Tags: c++, cgal

I am trying to apply `Delaunay_mesher_2::refine_mesh` to a set of numbered vertices (i.e. vertex class is `Triangulation_vertex_base_with_id_2`). I expect that any vertex created in the process should have `id()==0`. However it turns out to be not the case. Instead, the IDs have various positive/negative values.

I tried using `Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2`, but the result was the same.

More or less my code works like this:

```cpp
using K = CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel;
using Vb = CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_id_2<K>;
using Fb = CGAL::Delaunay_mesh_face_base_2<K>;
using Tds = CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<Vb, Fb>;
using CDT_Tag = CGAL::Exact_intersections_tag;
using CDT = CGAL::Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2<K, Tds, CDT_Tag>;
using Criteria = CGAL::Delaunay_mesh_size_criteria_2<CDT>;
CDT cdt;
CGAL::Delaunay_mesher_2<CDT, Criteria> mesher(cdt, Criteria(0.125, 0.5));
... // Add some points and constraints.
static const CDT::Point INFINITE_POINT = { 1e100, 1e100 };
std::vector<CDT::Point> seeds = { INFINITE_POINT };
mesher.set_seeds(seeds.begin(), seeds.end());
mesher.refine_mesh();

for (auto vertices_iter = cdt.finite_vertices_begin();
     vertices_iter != cdt.finite_vertices_end();
     ++vertices_iter) {
  // do something with vertices_iter->id().
}
```

Comment: What is the question? id is not initialized in this class.

Comment: The question is why id() of some vertices is not 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default-constructor of `CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_id_2<K>` does not initialize the `id` member:

```cpp
template < typename GT,
           typename Vb = Triangulation_vertex_base_2<GT> >
class Triangulation_vertex_base_with_id_2
  : public Vb
{
  int _id;

public:

  // [...]

  Triangulation_vertex_base_with_id_2()
    : Vb() {}
```

That means that `_id` is [default-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization):

> **Explanation**
>
> Default initialization is performed in three situations: [...]
>
> 3. when a base class or a non-static data member is not mentioned in a constructor initializer list and that constructor is called.

then read the next paragraph:

> The effects of default initialization are:
>
> - if T is a non-POD (until C++11) class type, the constructors are considered and subjected to overload resolution against the empty argument list. The constructor selected (which is one of the default constructors) is called to provide the initial value for the new object;
> - if T is an array type, every element of the array is
>     default-initialized;
> - otherwise, nothing is done: the objects with automatic storage duration (and their subobjects) are initialized to indeterminate values.

Here the subobject `_id` if of type `int`, and thus it is not a class or an array. That is why it is not initialized. The value will be whatever garbage was there in memory.

Comment: Ah indeed, so to fix it correctly I should inherit from `Triangulation_vertex_base_with_id_2` and initialize `id` explicitly.

Comment: Right. That is a good solution. You can also take that class template as an example: copy-paste it with a new name, and modify it as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

The id is not set by any algorithm. It give you only a possibility to set it for your needs.

Comment: Yes, but C++ standard says that the id should be default-initialized (in case of `int` the value should be 0). Somehow the value is not 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is some kind of a bug in CGAL (likely an undefined behaviour, because the result is different every time). It's hard to say for sure where it comes from, but UB sanitizer in GCC says there are at least places where null pointer is dereferenced.

As a workaround, one may use a mapping of `Vertex_handle` into `int` via `CGAL::Unique_hash_map`.